# Get a Sharepoint ListItem Based on Date?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I have a Sharepoint List which is sorted by a Report Date.

Within a Visual Webpart I have created an html report which references the ListItems.  One of the options on this Webpart is to change the date.  If the user changes the date I need to be able to retrieve the ListItem corresponding to that Date from the List.  Using c#, how can I get a handle on the Item in this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your answer here

- http://snahta.blogspot.com/2009/04/getting-list-item-updated-in-past-few.html
- Few more good tips @ http://snahta.blogspot.com/2009/07/spquery-few-important-things.html